# 403 Forbidden when introducing authorization on spring boot rest

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-security

I am with my first spring-boot project. I did succesfully configure it to check for authentication; if the user/password was wrong the method was not invoked (status 401 unauthorized), if it was right it succeeded.

Now I have added authorization with JSR250 and I am only getting 403 Access denied.

The WS:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/password")
public class ServicioPassword {
    @GetMapping(path = "ldap")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getLdap() {
        var authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        System.out.println("EN LDAP " + authentication.getPrincipal() + " - " + authentication.isAuthenticated());
        for (var authority : authentication.getAuthorities()) {
            System.out.println("Authority= " + authority);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("DE LDAP");
    }
```

When invoked, I get this on console:

> EN LDAP LdapUserDetailsImpl [Dn=cn=ivr_apl_user,ou=IVR,ou=Aplicaciones,dc=pre,dc=aplssib; Username=ivr_apl_user; Password=[PROTECTED]; Enabled=true; AccountNonExpired=true; CredentialsNonExpired=true; AccountNonLocked=true; Granted Authorities=[AGNI_OIMIVR]] - true
> Authority= AGNI_OIMIVR

Yet, if I add `@RolesAllowed("AGNI_OIMIVR")`, when I invoke it I get a 403 Forbidden.

The `MethodSecurityConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig
    extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration{   
}
```

I have kept the `WebSecurityConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    BindAuthenticator bindAuthenticator(
        final BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource) {
        var bindAuthenticator = new BindAuthenticator(contextSource);
        bindAuthenticator.setUserDnPatterns(new String[]{environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.ldap.userdnpattern")});
        return bindAuthenticator;
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider(
        final LdapAuthenticator ldapAuthenticator) {
        var ldapAuthenticationProvider = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticator);
        var ldapUserDetailsMapper = new CustomUserDetailsMapper();
        var ldapMemberRoles = environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.ldap.roleattributes");
        ldapUserDetailsMapper.setRoleAttributes(ldapMemberRoles.split(","));
        ldapUserDetailsMapper.setRolePrefix("");
        ldapAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(ldapUserDetailsMapper);
        return ldapAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(
        final HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .cors().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .httpBasic();

        return http.build();
    }
```

UPDATE: Adding log after setting `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE`:

Note that the line: `2022-07-07 13:04:27.464 WARN 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] e.s.d.o.s.ws.CustomUserDetailsMapper : createAuthority agni_oimivr` comes from a log from one of my custom classes.

> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.441 TRACE 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Found username 'ivr_apl_user' in Basic Authorization header
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.442 TRACE 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with LdapAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.444 TRACE 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator              : Attempting to bind as cn=ivr_apl_user,ou=[REDACTED]
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.444 TRACE 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.l.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource : Removing pooling flag for user cn=ivr_apl_user,ou=[REDACTED]
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.463 DEBUG 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator              : Bound cn=ivr_apl_user,ou=[REDACTED]
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.463 DEBUG 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.l.u.LdapUserDetailsMapper          : Mapping user details from context with DN cn=ivr_apl_user,ou=[REDACTED]
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.464  WARN 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] e.s.d.o.s.ws.CustomUserDetailsMapper     : createAuthority agni_oimivr
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.464 DEBUG 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.l.a.LdapAuthenticationProvider     : Authenticated user
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.465 DEBUG 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=LdapUserDetailsImpl [Dn=cn=ivr_apl_user,ou=IVR,ou=Aplicaciones,dc=pre,dc=aplssib; Username=ivr_apl_user; Password=[PROTECTED]; Enabled=true; AccountNonExpired=true; CredentialsNonExpired=true; AccountNonLocked=true; Granted Authorities=[AGNI_OIMIVR]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[AGNI_OIMIVR]]
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.465 TRACE 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/12)
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.465 TRACE 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : No saved request
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.465 TRACE 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/12)
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.466 TRACE 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/12)
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.466 TRACE 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=LdapUserDetailsImpl [Dn=cn=ivr_apl_user,ou=IVR,ou=Aplicaciones,dc=pre,dc=aplssib; Username=ivr_apl_user; Password=[PROTECTED]; Enabled=true; AccountNonExpired=true; CredentialsNonExpired=true; AccountNonLocked=true; Granted Authorities=[AGNI_OIMIVR]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[AGNI_OIMIVR]]
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.466 TRACE 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (10/12)
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.467 TRACE 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Preparing session with ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy (1/1)
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.467 DEBUG 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : The HttpSession is currently null, and the HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository is prohibited from creating an HttpSession (because the allowSessionCreation property is false) - SecurityContext thus not stored for next request
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.467 TRACE 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.467 TRACE 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking FilterSecurityInterceptor (12/12)
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.468 TRACE 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Did not re-authenticate UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=LdapUserDetailsImpl [Dn=cn=ivr_apl_user,ou=IVR,ou=Aplicaciones,dc=pre,dc=aplssib; Username=ivr_apl_user; Password=[PROTECTED]; Enabled=true; AccountNonExpired=true; CredentialsNonExpired=true; AccountNonLocked=true; Granted Authorities=[AGNI_OIMIVR]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[AGNI_OIMIVR]] before authorizing
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.468 TRACE 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorizing filter invocation [GET /password/ldap] with attributes [authenticated]
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.469 DEBUG 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [GET /password/ldap] with attributes [authenticated]
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.470 TRACE 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Did not switch RunAs authentication since RunAsManager returned null
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.470 DEBUG 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /password/ldap
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.471 TRACE 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Did not re-authenticate UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=LdapUserDetailsImpl [Dn=cn=ivr_apl_user,ou=IVR,ou=Aplicaciones,dc=pre,dc=aplssib; Username=ivr_apl_user; Password=[PROTECTED]; Enabled=true; AccountNonExpired=true; CredentialsNonExpired=true; AccountNonLocked=true; Granted Authorities=[AGNI_OIMIVR]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[AGNI_OIMIVR]] before authorizing
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.472 TRACE 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Authorizing ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity es.ssib.dtic.oimivr.service.ws.v1.ServicioPassword.getLdap(); target is of class [es.ssib.dtic.oimivr.service.ws.v1.ServicioPassword] with attributes [ROLE_AGNI_OIMIVR]
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.475 TRACE 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity es.ssib.dtic.oimivr.service.ws.v1.ServicioPassword.getLdap(); target is of class [es.ssib.dtic.oimivr.service.ws.v1.ServicioPassword] with attributes [ROLE_AGNI_OIMIVR] using AffirmativeBased [DecisionVoters=[org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Jsr250Voter@6797e2e2, org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@2ab76862, org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@152f6a2e], AllowIfAllAbstainDecisions=false]
> 2022-07-07 13:04:27.484 TRACE 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=LdapUserDetailsImpl [Dn=cn=ivr_apl_user,ou=IVR,ou=Aplicaciones,dc=pre,dc=aplssib; Username=ivr_apl_user; Password=[PROTECTED]; Enabled=true; AccountNonExpired=true; CredentialsNonExpired=true; AccountNonLocked=true; Granted Authorities=[AGNI_OIMIVR]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[AGNI_OIMIVR]] to access denied handler since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Acceso denegado
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:73) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:239) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
[...]
2022-07-07 13:04:27.497 DEBUG 81968 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl   : Responding with 403 status code

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share your request? Also, add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` to your `application.properties` to see in the console why the 403

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio The request is a simple GET request; if I change anything in the username/password I get a 401 so that part works ok. I have added the log after setting the `org.springframework.security` to `TRACE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Authentication` object of your authenticated user is:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=LdapUserDetailsImpl [Dn=cn=ivr_apl_user,ou=IVR,ou=Aplicaciones,dc=pre,dc=aplssib; Username=ivr_apl_user; Password=[PROTECTED]; Enabled=true; AccountNonExpired=true; CredentialsNonExpired=true; AccountNonLocked=true; Granted Authorities=[AGNI_OIMIVR]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[AGNI_OIMIVR]]
```

Note that the `GrantedAuthorities` is `Granted Authorities=[AGNI_OIMIVR]`, there is no `ROLE_` prefix there. When you add `@RolesAllowed("AGNI_OIMIVR")` to the method, the `ROLE_` prefix will be added automatically to the authority that you passed as an argument to the annotation, becoming `ROLE_AGNI_OIMIVR`.

Spring Security will try to match `ROLE_AGNI_OIMIVR` that is in the annotation with `AGNI_OIMIVR` that is in the granted authorities' property, but they do not match.

You have three options:

1. Change the role in LDAP to have the `ROLE_` prefix
2. Expose a Bean of `GrantedAuthorityDefaults` removing the `rolePrefix`, like so:

```java
@Bean
GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults() {
    return new GrantedAuthorityDefaults("");
}
```

3. Use `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('AGNI_OIMIVR')")`

Another tip would be to use the new `@EnableMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)` which uses the simplified `AuthorizationManager` API, improve logging, amongst others.

Comment: You were absolutely right, thank you very much.